# Do you shuffle the already played cards back into the deck when using the 'Winter Is Coming' card?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the Westeros decks I and II there is a 'Winter Is Coming' card, which says:

> Immediately shuffle this deck. Then draw and resolve a new card.

Are you meant to shuffle the cards of that deck that have already been played in previous rounds, or are they left out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes sense that you would put the discard pile back into the deck and re-shuffle - this is what we have always done in our games. This obviously means that you can have the reappearance of cards that have already been drawn once before.

It wouldn't make sense to just shuffle the remaining cards - what would be the difference between that and not shuffling the remaining cards? They're still unknown and already/still in a random order.

Comment: That's my thoughts too, but wanted clarification on the matter.